How to contract a function
Fix $a\in\mathbb{R}$ and let $g:[1,4]\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $g(x)=x+a(1-\ln(x))$. I want to find for what values of $a$ we have that $g(x)\in [1,4]$ for all $x\in[1,4]$. Note that
\begin{align*}
1\leq g(x)\iff 1\leq x+a(1-\ln(x))\iff 1-x\leq a(1-\ln(x))
\end{align*}
Observe that
\begin{align*}
1-x&\leq -\ln(x)\\
&< 1-\ln(x)\\
&< a(1-\ln(x)),
\end{align*}
the last inequality holds if $a>0$, then for $a>0$ we have $1\leq g(x)$. I have tried to find the values of $a$ for which $g(x)\leq 4$, but my attempt was not successfully completed. Can anyone help me with this problem please?

The domain of the function is compact, and the function is continuos, so it admits a global Maximum $g(M)$ and a minimum $g(m)$. Moreover, by the Mean Value Theorem, then the image of $g$ is $[g(m), g(M)]$. Hence we have to find the Maximum and minimum of $g$:
$$g'(x)=1-\frac{a}{x}=\frac{x-a}{x}\geq 0 \implies x\geq a.$$
If $1< a< 4$, then $x=a$ is a minimum point and the maximum point is either $x=1$ or $x=4$. However
$$ g(1)=1+a\geq g(4)=4+a(1-\ln(4)) \iff \ln(4)a\geq 3 \iff a\geq \frac{3}{\ln(4)}.$$
Thus for $1< a \leq \frac{3}{\ln(4)}$ the minimum point is $x=a$ and the maximum point is $x=4$.
Instead, if $\frac{3}{\ln(4)}\leq a<4 $ the minimum point is $x=a$ and the maximum point is $x=1$.
Instead, if $a \leq 1$, then $g'(x)\geq 0$ and so $g$ is increasing on its domain $[1,4]$, that means $x=1$ is the minimum point and $x=4$ is the maximum point.
We consider finally $a\geq 4$. Then $g'(x)\leq 0$ and so $g$ is decreasing on $[1,4]$ and then the minimum point $x=4$ and the maximum points is $x=1$.
Now that we obtained the minimum and maximum points of $g$ for each possibile value of $a$, we need to find $a$ such that $g(m)=1$ and $g(M)=4$.
If  $a\leq 1$, then
$$ g(1)=1+a=1 \implies a=0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(4)=4+a(1-\ln(4))=4 \implies a=0$$
Thus $a=0$ is a possible solution.
If $1< a \leq \frac{3}{\ln(4)}$, then
$$ g(a)=a+a(1-\ln(a))=1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(4)=4+a(1-\ln(4))=4 \implies a=0$$
That it is impossible.
If $\frac{3}{\ln(4)}\leq a<4$ then
$$ g(a)=a+a(1-\ln(a))=1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(1)=1+a=4 \implies a=3$$
that it is impossible too.
Finally, if $a\geq 4$, then
$$ g(4)=1=4+a(1-ln(4)) \implies  \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(1)=4=1+a \implies a=3$$
that it is impossible too.
Thus the only possibile case is $a=0$.
Instead, if you want to understand for which values of $a$ you have $g([1,4])\subseteq [1,4]$  it is sufficient to use a similar approach:
If $a\leq 1$ we need to impose
$$ g(1)=1+a\geq 1 \implies a\geq 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(4)=4+a(1-ln(4))\leq 4 \implies a\geq 0 $$
Thus a set of solutions is $0\leq a\leq 1$.
Instead if  $1< a \leq \frac{3}{\ln(4)}$, then
$$ g(a)=a+a(1-\ln(a))\geq 1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(4)=4+a(1-\ln(4))\leq 4 \implies a\geq 0$$
Thus another set of solutions is $1< a\leq \frac{3}{\ln(4)}$.
Let us consider now $\frac{3}{\ln(4)}\leq a<4$, so that we need to impose
$$ g(a)=a+a(1-\ln(a))\geq 1 \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(1)=1+a\leq 4 \implies a\leq 3$$
In this case another set of solutions to add is $\frac{3}{\ln(4)}\leq a\leq 3$.
It remains to study the case $a\geq 4$:
$$ g(4)=4+a(1-ln(4))\geq 4 \implies a\leq 0 \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(1)=1+a\leq 4 \implies a=\leq 3$$
Since $a\geq 4$ and $a\leq 0$, then we don't need to add another piece of solutions.
Thus at the end, studying case by case as we done, we obtain that $g([1,4])\subseteq [1,4]$ if and only if $0\leq a\leq 3$.

Hi, thanks for your answer. How do you know $\frac{x-a}{x}\geq 0$?

@RataMágica that inequality is the standard way to study the sign of the derivative and thus the critical points

Then are you assuming that?

It seems to work for every $0 \leqslant a \leqslant 3$ (check this).

@Ceru, Yes, but I don't know how to prove it

I do not assume that $(x-a)/x\geq 0$, I was studying the sign of the derivative. And this sign depends on the position of $a$ with respect to $[1,4]$.

@Ceru No, It seems that it works only for $a=0$, you have to look to the image, whose interval is never equal to $[1,4]$ except for $a=0$.

@FedericoFallucca, but I think as the problem is posed, we search values of $a$ for which the image is a subset of that interval, the case $a=0$ is a particular case

One moment, it is enough that the image is a subset of that it is equal to $[1,4]$?

@FedericoFallucca I think he meant that $a$ must verify $g([1,4]) \subseteq [1,4]$. But $g([1,4]) = [1,4]$ iff $a=0$, in that I completely agree with you.

Ah I understood. Then I have studied and added also this weaker case :)
